# How to pass values with distinct foreign key to the view in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I have a 1:m relationship in my code first classes. The orders instance of my view show values with unique OrderID. Since one Customer can have many orders, the foreign key CustID is not unique in this view.

```
public class Customers
{

    public int CustomerID { get; set; }


    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "{0} cannot exceed {1} characters")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }

    public string email {get; set;}
   public List<Orders> orders { get; set; }
}
```

Orders class:

```
public class Orders
{

        [Key]
        public int OrdersID { get; set; }
        public int OrderName { get; set; }
        public int? CustomerID { get; set; }
        public virtual Customers customer { get; set; }

}
```

Below is my controller:

```
 private custContext db = new custContext();

    //
    // GET: /cust/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var cust = db.orders.Include(c => c.customer).Take(10);
        return View(cust.ToList());
    }
```

How do I show only **distinct Customers** in my view with their **OrderNames** in the same view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think about renaming your classes and attributes to conform to the naming conventions. Use singular names like public class Order ... instead of Orders. Use Id as the primary key name for all fields. Start all your attributes with capital letters (pascal case) This will help the framework understand your model.

To get the data you want, just use:

```
var cust = db.Customers.Include("orders").Take(10);
```

If you make the convention changes this would become:

```
var cust = db.Customers.Include("Orders").Take(10);
```

You would need to setup the DbSet in your data context but it looks like you already figured this out since you are using db.Orders. Anyway here is the code (with Customer converted to singular):

```
public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

Comment: How should I show/read  one of the properties in the view then? I have this in my controller var cust = db.Customers.Include("Orders");. In my view I tried this @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Orders**.Ordername**). the bold is the one thats wrong. Its many OrderName items here and how do I get to read only one OrderName item related to the customer?

Answer (score 0):

In View : Start with ...

```
@model IList<ProjectName.Customers>
```

If you want to bind multi record then

```
foreach(var c in Model)
{
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => c.OrderName) 
}
```

Otherwise `@model.Orders.OrderNames....`

Comment: Please check the code I have added for my controller. When I try your code, using the customers model I can not bind or read OrderName.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var cust = db.Customers.get().Select(x => new Customers
                {
                    CustomerID = x.CustomerID,
                    OrderName = x.Orders.OrderName,
                });
        return View(cust.Take(10).ToList());
    }
```

View:

```
@model IList<ProjectName.Customers>

foreach(var c in Model)
{
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => c.OrderName) 
}
```

Comment: I get this error from implementation of your code. **The entity or complex type 'ProjectName.Model.Customers' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.**